# How do I extract numeric values from strings and add those numbers?

Tags: java, arrays, string, input, java.util.scanner

The user inputs an array like input that looks like this: `int[]num=new int[]{1,2,3}`. The program should accept only the numbers (1,2,3) and remove the comma to add those numbers. Finally it should print out the sum. How do I solve it?

[NOTE: I want that the user can input any length of numbers inside the curly brace.]

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Step:1. This program takes input in the following structure that looks like array declaration:\nint[]num=new int[]{1,2,3}");
    System.out.println("Step:2. The program should ignore all the strings and accept only the numeric value (i.e. in this case it is: 1,2,3).");
    System.out.println("Step:3. The program then add the numners (i.e. 1+2+3) and print out the sum");
    System.out.println("***********************\n");

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Write input: ");
    while (true) {
        String array = sc.nextLine();
        if (array.contains("int")) {

            int convertArrIntoNum = Integer.parseInt(array.substring(20, 2));
            //remove the comma in between of each numeric value
            //add the numbers
            //print out the result
           // System.out.println("The sum of the array: " + sumResult);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong input! Try again");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can just substring between the two "{","}" and then call a split function on the string returned by that.   Hint: 1.Use the `indexOf` from the string class to sub string it. 2. String[] nums = thatString.split(",");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should work even for float and double.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestMainResuse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Step:1. This program takes input in the following structure that looks like array declaration:\nint[]num=new int[]{1,2,3}");
        System.out.println("Step:2. The program should ignore all the strings and accept only the numeric value (i.e. in this case it is: 1,2,3).");
        System.out.println("Step:3. The program then add the numners (i.e. 1+2+3) and print out the sum");
        System.out.println("***********************\n");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Write input: ");
        while (true) {
            try {
                String array = sc.nextLine();
                if (array.contains("int") || array.contains("float") || array.contains("double")) {

                    double sum = 0;
                    int start = array.indexOf('{');
                    int end = array.indexOf('}');
                    String strNum = array.substring(start+1, end);
                    String[] strArray = strNum.split(",");
                    for (String s : strArray) {
                        sum += Double.parseDouble(s.trim());  
                    }
                    System.out.printf("The sum of the array: %.5f", sum);

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Wrong input! Try again");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Wrong input! Try again");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Test 1

```
Write input: 
double[] d= new double[]{1.2,3.333}
The sum of the array: 4.53300
```

Test 2

```
Write input: 
int[]num=new int[]{1,2,3}
The sum of the array: 6.00000
```

Test 3

```
Write input: 
float[] num = new float[]{9.1,0.5,0.6}
The sum of the array: 10.20000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `String array` using `{` and `}` as starting and ending position.
Then you can split using `,` as delimiter. Then convert into integer using `parseInt` and add to `total`.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String a = "int[]num=new int[]{1,2,3,3,1,2}";
    
    if (a.substring(a.indexOf('{') + 1, a.indexOf('}')).matches("^[1-3,]+")) {
        String[] b = a.substring(a.indexOf('{') + 1, a.indexOf('}')).split(",");
        int sum = 0;
        for (String s: b)
        {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(s);
        }
            System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/OH5dr6) is the working demo. This is limited to the input you gave. Tweak around if you think input can be different.

EDIT:
I didn't see that numbers can only be 1,2 or 3. We can use `regex` to validate input

Comment: This will also work for input as - `{2,45,4}` and it would be wrong because that doesn't meet the OP's requirement ..

Comment: @hagrawal Oh. I didn't read that part. We can add conditions to check if it contains anything else than `1,2,3`

Comment: @hagrawal check edit. It only accepts `1,2,3` only :)

Comment: No, what I mean is OP want input to be a valid array declaration, you answer will also work if input as `{1,2,44}` is passed. Any number can be passed but it should be valid array declaration.

Comment: @hagrawal Question wording is confusing. `The program should accept only the numbers (1,2,3)...` I guess the OP wouln't mind if you can edit the question so we can answer better. I think you understood what OP means

Comment: I can do that but it would be inappropriate for me to do the same, I will leave it for OP for elaborate ..

Comment: sam2090, I think Jags has a perfect answer for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Step:1. This program takes input in the following structure that looks like array declaration:\nint[]num=new int[]{1,2,3}");
System.out.println("Step:2. The program should ignore all the strings and accept only the numeric value (i.e. in this case it is: 1,2,3).");
System.out.println("Step:3. The program then add the numners (i.e. 1+2+3) and print out the sum");
System.out.println("***********************\n");
     int SUM = 0 ;
    try {


 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter array length");
    int arraylength = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter number");



int[] numbers = new int[arraylength];

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{    
    while (!sc.hasNextInt()) 
        sc.next();

    numbers[i] = sc.nextInt();
    SUM+=numbers[i] ;
} 
        System.out.println( "sum is "+ SUM);    ;

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("enter interger");
    }
}
```